# Optimization with variable number of arguments

Tags: optimization, matlab

I need to optimize a problem with variable number of arguments. The problem is something like that: I have a function $F$, now the function F takes input of position $(x_0,y_0)$, generates three output: two position coordinate $x_1, y_1$ and a cost function $C_1$.

That is, in MATLAB, I can make a function $[C_1, x_1, y_1] = F(x_0,y_0)$;

now the output coordinate goes to the same function again to generate second cost, $C_2$ and I need to keep adding $C_1 + C_2$ and so on until I get a desired cost $C_{opt} = C_1 + C_2 + .....$ . So my variables for this optimization problem is also variable, I don't know how many times I need to calculate the function $F$ before the optimization starts and the total number of variables is also not known.

How can I solve this problem. Any insight to address this problem will be welcomed. I just need some clue to start this. I would like to use Particle Swarm Optimization problem with MATLAB.

Thanks in advance.
Khalid

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but it seems to me, that you have exactly two variables, $x_0$ and $y_0$; all the Cs are calculated from those. You could (again, if I understand it correctly) make a function, which takes x, y, and $C_0$ as its arguments and instead of returning a new C, it adds the new C to the provided $C_0$ and returns the sum.

Comment: To be a control problem you should have additional inputs regarding $F(p)$ otherwise your problem is a plain fixed point problem. The correct problem could be: Given $\Phi(p), p\in \Omega$ determine an orbit $p_{k+1} = F(p_k, u_k)$ such that $\sum_k\Phi(p_k)$ is extremal. The dynamics for $p_{k+1}=F(p_k)$ is a fixed point dynamics and is independent on $\Phi,\Omega$